# Extjs - change checkbox label

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs4

i have a xtype "checkbox", i want change boxlabel by dynamic

```
{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    id: 'abc',
    checked: false,
    uncheckedValue: '0',
    inputValue: 1,
    boxLabel: 'change',
    name:'abc'
}
```

i using

```
Ext.getCmp('abc').setBoxLabel('not working'); // it's not working
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('abc').update('loss checkbox'); // it's working but checkbox's disappear.
```

How can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ext JS 4.2+ use `setBoxLabel()`

In Ext JS 4.1+ I've just found this workaround can help:

```
Ext.getCmp('abc').getEl().down('label.x-form-cb-label').update('New Label')
```

Comment: what about changing the label before the checkbox is rendered

Answer (score 1):

`getBoxLabel` should be working (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/pzKAH/)).

Maybe what you want to use is `fieldLabel` and [`setFieldLabel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-method-setFieldLabel)?

Answer (score 0):

**A cleaner approach (IMO)**

**For ExtJs 4.1.1 (this was officially added in later versions of the framework)**

I found the override recommended by Condor https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71968-Set-Checkbox-boxLabel-dynamically to be the best option because this works even if the checkbox is not rendered which is not the case in DrakES solution.

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Checkbox, {
    setBoxLabel: function(boxLabel){
        this.boxLabel = boxLabel;
        if(this.rendered){
            //NOTICE I CHANGED THIS LINE FROM THE ONE IN THE ORIGINAL SENCHA FORUM
            this.getEl().down('label.x-form-cb-label').update('New Label');
        }
    }
});
```

**Now you can use `.setBoxLabel()` :)**